# TypeError Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i'm creating a react-redux todo app, getting this error when click on view in UI. i'm trying to view each todo but getting this error, i've tried many times to get out of this but still getting this error.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const SingleTodoPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { todoId } = match.params;

  const todo = useSelector((state) => {
    state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
      <p>{todo.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-hmcpl?file=/src/App.js) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

When you configure your store you add your `TodoReducer` reducer as `todo`, not `todos`:

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todo: TodoReducer
  }
});
```

In the selector you reference `state.todos`:

```
const todo = useSelector((state) => {
  state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
});
```

Second issue is that your selector needs to also return a value.

## Solution

Reference the state correctly/consistently by doing one of the following.

1. Update the reducer name to match usage in selector

   ```
   export default configureStore({
     reducer: {
       todos: TodoReducer
     }
   });
   ```
2. Update your selector usage to match root reducer

   ```
   const todo = useSelector((state) => {
     state.todo.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
   });
   ```

Fix the selector to also return a value.

```
const todo = useSelector((state) => {
  return state.todo.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
});
```

Since `array.prototype.find` also returns `undefined` if no match is found your UI should handle this. Conditionally render the matched result or null if no `todo` is found.

```
export const SingleTodoPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { todoId } = match.params;

  const todo = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.todo.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
  });

  return todoId ? (
    <div>
      <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
      <p>{todo.description}</p>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

[image: Edit typeerror-cannot-read-property-find-of-undefined]